# Why Kivy uses floats instead of integers?

Tags: kivy

I've just started with Kivy and note that it uses float values instead of conventional integers. For example, the X and Y values of a specific widgets goes from 0 to 1, instead of 0 to 100. Rarer still, RGB values goes from 0 to 1 too, instead of the conventional 0 to 255. This could be a little uncomfortable.

Is there any performance reason behind this, just convention, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what OpenGL uses, which Kivy is ultimately a wrapper around, so it's easiest to use it consistently.

I don't know if there's a technical reason for this, though perhaps it has to do with the 0.0-1.0 float range being much more highly resolved than having only 256 values available.

I think there might be a function to convert 0-255 to 0.0-1.0 somewhere (maybe in kivy.utils), though of course it's trivial to write your own.